# Dynamic array of bytes to string

Tags: arrays, string, memory, byte, delphi-xe7

For a project, I need to read a name inside a TrueType font file (.ttf). I written a code to do that, inspirated from a c++ example. Here is the code:

```pascal
TWByteArray     = array of Byte;
TWAnsiCharArray = array of AnsiChar;

...

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class function TWStringHelper.ByteToStr(const bytes: TWByteArray): string;
begin
    SetLength(Result, Length(bytes));

    if Length(Result) > 0 then
        Move(bytes[0], Result[1], Length(bytes));
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class function TWStringHelper.UniStrToByte(const str: UnicodeString): TWByteArray;
begin
    SetLength(Result, Length(str) * SizeOf(WideChar));

    if (Length(Result) > 0) then
        Move(str[1], Result[0], Length(Result));
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class function TWStringHelper.BytesToUniStr(const bytes: TWByteArray): UnicodeString;
begin
    SetLength(Result, Length(bytes) div SizeOf(WideChar));

    if Length(Result) > 0 then
        Move(bytes[0], Result[1], Length(bytes));
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

...        

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class function TWControlFont.SwapWord(value: Word): Word;
begin
    Result := MakeWord(HiByte(value), LoByte(value));
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class function TWControlFont.SwapLong(value: LongInt): LongInt;
begin
    Result := MakeLong(SwapWord(HiWord(value)), SwapWord(LoWord(value)));
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class function TWControlFont.GetFontNameFromFile(const fileName: UnicodeString): UnicodeString;
var
    pFile:       TFileStream;
    offsetTable: ITTFOffsetTable;
    dirTable:    ITTFDirectoryTable;
    nameHeader:  ITTFNameTableHeader;
    nameRecord:  ITTFNameRecord;
    nameBuffer:  TWByteArray;//TWAnsiCharArray;
    i:           USHORT;
    found:       Boolean;

    test2: string;
    test3: UnicodeString;
    test: Integer;

    const name:  array [0..3] of Byte = (Ord('n'), Ord('a'), Ord('m'), Ord('e'));
begin
    // open font file
    pFile := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead);

    // succeeded?
    if (not Assigned(pFile)) then
        Exit;

    try
        pFile.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

        // read TTF offset table
        if (pFile.Read(offsetTable, SizeOf(ITTFOffsetTable)) <> SizeOf(ITTFOffsetTable)) then
            Exit;

        offsetTable.m_NumOfTables  := SwapWord(offsetTable.m_NumOfTables);
        offsetTable.m_MajorVersion := SwapWord(offsetTable.m_MajorVersion);
        offsetTable.m_MinorVersion := SwapWord(offsetTable.m_MinorVersion);

        // is truetype font and version is 1.0?
        if ((offsetTable.m_MajorVersion <> 1) or (offsetTable.m_MinorVersion <> 0)) then
            Exit;

        found := False;

        // iterate through file tables
        if (offsetTable.m_NumOfTables > 0) then
            for i := 0 to offsetTable.m_NumOfTables - 1 do
            begin
                // read table
                if (pFile.Read(dirTable, SizeOf(ITTFDirectoryTable)) <> SizeOf(ITTFDirectoryTable)) then
                    Exit;

                // found name table?
                if (CompareMem(@dirTable.m_Tag, @name, 4) = True) then
                begin
                    found             := True;
                    dirTable.m_Length := SwapLong(dirTable.m_Length);
                    dirTable.m_Offset := SwapLong(dirTable.m_Offset);
                    break;
                end;
            end;

        // found name table?
        if (not found) then
            Exit;

        // seek to name location
        pFile.Position := dirTable.m_Offset;

        // read name table header
        if (pFile.Read(nameHeader, SizeOf(ITTFNameTableHeader)) <> SizeOf(ITTFNameTableHeader)) then
            Exit;

        nameHeader.m_NRCount       := SwapWord(nameHeader.m_NRCount);
        nameHeader.m_StorageOffset := SwapWord(nameHeader.m_StorageOffset);

        // iterate through name records
        if (nameHeader.m_NRCount > 0) then
            for i := 0 to nameHeader.m_NRCount - 1 do
            begin
                // read name record
                if (pFile.Read(nameRecord, SizeOf(ITTFNameRecord)) <> SizeOf(ITTFNameRecord)) then
                    Exit;

                nameRecord.m_NameID := SwapWord(nameRecord.m_NameID);

                // found font name?
                if (nameRecord.m_NameID = 1) then
                begin
                    // get font name length and offset
                    nameRecord.m_StringLength := SwapWord(nameRecord.m_StringLength);
                    nameRecord.m_StringOffset := SwapWord(nameRecord.m_StringOffset);

                    if (nameRecord.m_StringLength = 0) then
                        continue;

                    // calculate and seek to font name offset
                    pFile.Position := dirTable.m_Offset + nameRecord.m_StringOffset + nameHeader.m_StorageOffset;

                    try
                        SetLength(nameBuffer, nameRecord.m_StringLength + 1);
                        //REM FillChar(nameBuffer[0], nameRecord.m_StringLength + 1, $0);

                        // read font name from file
                        if (pFile.Read(nameBuffer[0], nameRecord.m_StringLength)
                            <> nameRecord.m_StringLength)
                        then
                            Exit;

                        nameBuffer[nameRecord.m_StringLength] := $0;

                        //OutputDebugString(PChar(nameBuffer));
                        //TWMemoryHelper.SwapBytes(nameBuffer[0], nameRecord.m_StringLength);
                        //OutputDebugString(PChar(nameBuffer));

                        //test := StringElementSize(RawByteString(@nameBuffer[0]));
                        //Result := TWStringHelper.BytesToUniStr(nameBuffer);
                        //Result := UnicodeString(AnsiString(TWStringHelper.ByteToStr(nameBuffer)));
                        //REM Result := UnicodeString(nameBuffer);
                        test2 := TWStringHelper.ByteToStr(nameBuffer);
                        OutputDebugStringA(PAnsiChar(test2));
                        test3 := UnicodeString(PAnsiChar(test2));
                        OutputDebugStringW(PWideChar(test3));    
                        Result := test3;
                        OutputDebugStringW(PWideChar(test3));

                    finally
                        SetLength(nameBuffer, 0);
                    end;

                    break;
                end;
            end;
    finally
        pFile.Free;
    end;
end;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This code works well until the final part of the GetFontNameFromFile() function. There, things start to get complicated. Indeed, I'm unable to convert the nameBuffer byte array to a string in a correct manner.

The first problem I met is that the nameBuffer may be a simple ASCII string, or an UTF16 string, depend on file (I tried with the emoji.ttf available in FireFox, that returns an ASCII string, and Tahoma.ttf from my Win installation, that returns a UTF16 string). I need a way to determine that, and I don't know if there is a function or class in the VCL to do that.

The second problem is the conversion itself. The above code works more or less, but I feel that is not a correct solution. When I try to convert to an UnicodeString directly from nameBuffer, I get some strange crashes. If I try to convert nameBuffer to an AnsiString, the conversion seems success, however a conversion like UnicodeString(AnsiString(nameBuffer)) fails.

And the code seems to be full of memory issues. As I'm new with Delphi, I'm not very comfortable with the memory usage. For example, I suspect several issues with the byte array when I activate the

```
FillChar(nameBuffer[0], nameRecord.m_StringLength + 1, $0);
```

line.

So anybody can analyse this code and points me what I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: And what language are you working in?

Comment: Delphi with RAD Studio XE7, sorry

Comment: Very many errors here most of which stem from lack of knowledge of the language. Going to be arduous for us to fix them all.

Comment: Hi David. Indeed I begin with Delphi and I'm aware that the quality of the above code is probably very low. However I posted it integrally to give the context in order to know a specific issue, that is why the final conversion from byte array to Unicode string does not work well at the end of the function. It's due to a conversion error? Or a memory issue? However I did not expect that ALL the code would be corrected. However if you have the desire and the time to show me at least my biggest mistakes, I would be grateful. I want to learn, and all information is welcome. Regards

Comment: I use firefox but I don't have any emoji.ttf on my system. Anyway, you may have mis-diagnosed the problem, all name strings in a Windows font is unicode ([link](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm)).

Comment: Hi Sertac, thank you for your reply, in fact I found these ASCII encoded texts in several .ttf files that were not provided by Microsoft. In this present case, I found the font to which I refer above inside the FireFox source code, you can download it from here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7C-RwCTA9qaUW5GbFRHOGUzTTA